# How not to overwrite an existing file when both are named by RANDOM special variable

Tags: linux, shell

I have written a basic script for saving the not-empty error files from the different parts of a big program because they are deleted after a while.

I thought I solved the problem by saving them under different names using the bash special variable `$RANDOM`. It worked well, but now I just realized that I have lost some error files, probably because it was overwritten by random naming procedure. How can I save the new (not empty) error files as well without overwriting the older ones?

My script is:

```
while [ ! -e ${myfile} ]; do
 for FILE in $( find dirnames -name job.err )
 do
    if [[ -s ${FILE} ]] ; then
      echo ${FILE} >> LIST
      cp ${FILE} COLLECT/job_${RANDOM}.err
    fi
 done
 sleep 3600
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mktemp` to create a file name that's guaranteed to be unique.  For example:

```
cp "${FILE}" "COLLECT/$(mktemp job_XXXXXXXXX)"
```

You lose the ".err" suffix in the above case, but you could work around that with some additional code if you really want it.

Comment: Thanks very much! Finally, I have used the one that uses the time, but I memorized the mktemp as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for a simple solution, just add the time since the epoch in nanoseconds to the filename. While it won't guarantee an absence of collisions, it will at least make them very unlikely, especially when combined with the random value. E.g.

```
cp ${FILE} COLLECT/job_${RANDOM}-$(date +%s.%N).err
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$RANDOM` gives you an 1 in 32767 chance of having a name collision. That's pretty likely.

You already know how to check if a file exists, use that same method to approach your file copy:

```
copy="COLLECT/job_${RANDOM}.err"
while [[ -e "$copy" ]] ; do
    copy="COLLECT/job_${RANDOM}.err"
done
cp "${FILE}" "$copy"
```

Of course, the closer you get to 32767 files, the harder it will try to find a free destination. It would be better to use a scheme that didn't depend on randomness.

Comment: This could still overwrite an existing file if the script is run multiple times in parallel (for example, if it's run frequently from cron and takes awhile to complete).  There's a brief window of time in there between when file existence is checked and when the file is created.  If two processes both check for a particular name at the same time, they will both see that it doesn't exist and then both attempt to create it.  This could be addressed by only allowing a single instance of the script to run at once, for example using `shlock`.

Comment: Thanks very much. Although, I did not use your idea, I can use it in another case.